# how to vertically center text beside image

Tags: html, css

Whatever I seem to do I have a problem making the take vertically center alongside of the image.

Any ideas of why this is? I've searched but to no avail, any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

(You may have to make the results window wider to see what I am talking about.)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mbM7C/4/)

HTML:

```
<div class="first">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
       Quisque varius pulvinar imperdiet. Cras quam orci, <br> 
       Duis vulputate risus rutrum, elementum purus non,</p>
    <img class="ipad" src="http://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/ipad-mini-scaled-1.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.first {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 0;
}

.first p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
}

.ipad {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49.2%;
}
```

Comment: The image isn't showing in the Fiddle. You might have to give the `src` a full path, not a relative path.

Comment: sorry about that, just updated it with a generic ipad image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following CSS may do the trick:

```css
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.first {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 0;
}

.first p {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
}

.ipad {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49.2%;
}
```

Apply `vertical-align: middle` to `.first p` and `.ipad`.

The vertical-align property is not inherited, so you need to specify it for the child elements that need adjusting.

**Reference:** http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align

See fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/UwffH/

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use `<table>` but it's not a good programming practice.

HTML:

```
<div class="first">
    <table border='0'><tr><td>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque varius pulvinar imperdiet. Cras quam orci, <br> Duis vulputate risus rutrum, elementum purus non,  </p></td><td>
        <img class="ipad" src="http://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/ipad-mini-scaled-1.jpg"></td></tr></table>
                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.first {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 0;
}

.first p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
}

.ipad {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```