# How to vertically center an image besides h1?

Tags: html, css

how can I vertically center an image besides a h1, even if the h1 wraps on page-resize with css?
See jsfiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/JJvG6/

**HTML**:

```
<div>
  <div id="img"><img></img></div>
  <div id="h1"><h1>This Div and the div with the picture should always be vertically centered, when page resizes and h1 wraps.</h1></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div #img {
    float: left
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you are aware the id=h1 is not the same as `<h1>`. Your sample CSS css needs to include what #h1 is supposed to do

Comment: um it's supposed to align vertically? Not really sure what your question is... What I want is, the image and the h1 should always be centered vertically. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any CSS for #h1?

Comment: no, not yet. Do you? ;)

Comment: Oh boy a bunch of things: Tried to use 2 divs with display table / table cell properties, negative margins 50% and position relative them back to center, but that didnt work because of the unknown dimensions - this is for a fluid/responsive design. My h1 is in a div just to get a better hold of it. Go ahead, free it if this helps in centering the image and the h1 vertically. Thank You!

Comment: Okay this has the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049429/how-to-vertically-center-text-beside-image?rq=1

Comment: That doesn't answer your question. If you make the div taller in the answer you linked to, the image doesn't center vertical, it stays at the top right.

Comment: Which Fiddle did you click on?
I meant the second one, the one in the first answer that has been marked accepted. Here is a direkt link:
http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/UwffH/
Sorry for the confusion! And thank you.

Comment: Right. In that jsfiddle, add `height: 650px; border: 1px solid black;` to the `.first` css. The image doesn't align vertically.

Comment: Oh okay I get you. But to me it doesn't really matter, since all I wanted was the img to be centered vertically respectively to the h1 (p in the example), not the entire div. And since the conataining div contains only the h1, the height will always fit the bill. So everythings good here :) But thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Based on some code Shredder used to show how using a table would solve the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/JLcgs/), you can instead [use non-table elements and apply `display: table` and `display: table-cell`](http://jsfiddle.net/JLcgs/1/) (and [other `display` values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) as necessary) to create the same thing using semantics-neutral elements.

(do note that the two examples are spaced slightly differently because of browser default values for table CSS - there will not be any extra space if using `<div>`s instead)

---

html

```html
<div>
    <div><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/avatar_207d7520c3c8_128.png" /></div>
    <div><h1>This Div and the div with the picture should always be vertically centered, when page resizes and h1 wraps. And this text could go on for who knows how long.. blah blah blah. random text And this text could go on for who knows how long.. blah blah blah. random text</h1></div>
</div>
```

css

```css
div {
    display: table;
}

div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're long term css/html goals are here, but perhaps a table (/frets) would benefit you more in this situation..

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/avatar_207d7520c3c8_128.png" /></td>
        <td><h1>This Div and the div with the picture should always be vertically centered, when page resizes and h1 wraps. And this text could go on for who knows how long.. blah blah blah. random text And this text could go on for who knows how long.. blah blah blah. random text</h1></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JJvG6/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I was thinking about tables, but naahh :) It really is no table content, so Im kinda reluctant to its use.

Comment: -1 for terrible use of tables. Use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` instead to make other elements act like table elements.

Comment: @Shredder [Your code](http://jsfiddle.net/JLcgs/), [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/JLcgs/1/). It's pretty simple.

Comment: @Nightfirecat Nice. I tried doing that, but I was doing it wrong. Make it an answer.